# IE 9 - BHO, not loaded after enabled by the user

Tags: internet-explorer-9, bho

I have C++ BHO that works in IE 8. In IE 9 (first launch), its disable until the users clicks on 'Enable' button. However, even after the 'Enable' click, the BHO is loaded only after IE restart.
I debugged this issue by putting some logs in the constructor of my BHO. It is not called after the user clicks on 'Enable'.
Have anyone experienced such issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that after the user enables it, it's enabled in new windows/tabs only, not existing ones.